# link markers to custom styled map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using samples from [Customizing the Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple) I created two custom styled map types. Now my map has four tabs.

I would like to display green markers on the green map (tab), and red markers on the red map (tab). I haven't seen a similar question, is this even possible with this approach or do I need to look into something else?

EDIT: during preview  I could see red and green maps (tabs) but after posting they are not showing in the snippet. There should be four options for the map:

Map Satellite red green

Not sure why it looks different after posting.

```js
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51, 4),
            zoom:8,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: ["roadmap", "satellite", "red", "green"],
            },
        });

        var red = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
        [
          {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "stylers": [
              {
                "visibility": "on"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        { name: "red" }
        );

        map.mapTypes.set("red", red);
        map.setMapTypeId("red");

        var green = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
        [
          {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "stylers": [
              {
                "visibility": "on"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        { name: "green" }
        );

        map.mapTypes.set("green", green);
        map.setMapTypeId("green");


        var markers = [];

        // make random red, yellow, blue markers
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.11 - Math.random(), 4.11 - Math.random());
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng, 
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png',
                label: '${i}',
                map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.11 - Math.random(),4.11 - Math.random());
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng, 
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow.png',
                label: '${i}',
                map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.11 - Math.random(),4.11 - Math.random());
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng, 
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png',
                label: '${i}',
                map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }

        // match cluster icon to markers
        var calc = function(markers, numStyles) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if (markers[i].getIcon().indexOf("red.png") > -1) {
                    return {text: markers.length, index: 3}; // index of red
                }else if (markers[i].getIcon().indexOf("yellow.png") > -1) {
                return {text: markers.length, index: 2}; // index of yellow
                }else if (markers[i].getIcon().indexOf("green.png") > -1) {
                    return {text: markers.length, index: 1};// index of blue
                }
            }
        }

        // define cluster icons
        var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15, styles: [{
                height: 50,
                url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlearchive/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m1.png",
                width: 50
            },
            {
                height: 50,
                url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlearchive/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m2.png",
                width: 50
            },
            {
                height: 50,
                url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlearchive/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m3.png",
                width: 50
            }]
        };
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
        markerCluster.setCalculator(calc);
    }
```

```css
#map {
            height: 80%;
          }
          /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
```

```html
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.42&key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>

    <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you push red markers to a `red` array, green markers to a `green` array, etc. then display the corresponding markers when the map type changes? Or I didn't understand your question...

Comment: I did not know how to do that and what to search for. Found some articles on tracking map type changes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the question one thing that was not overly clear is whether or not the colour of the `cluster` icon should be the same as the colour of the icons. The default, numerically indexed, available colours do not include `green` yet your code does specifically reference this colour - as an icon `green` is perfectly fine however. Because of this the following might only be "close" to the initial requirement as there is no `Green`.

If you were hosting the various cluster images on your own server it is trivial to create a new icon in green!

With that in mind perhaps the following will be of use -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: Clustered Markers with Custom "Map Stylers"</title>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
            .label{
                padding:0.25rem;
                border:2px solid gray;
                border-radius:0.5rem;
                background:whitesmoke;
                text-align:center;
            }
            .blue{}
            .yellow{color:black!important;background:yellow}
            .red{}
            .pink{color:black!important;background:pink;}
            .purple{}
        </style>
        <script src='//developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js'></script>
        <script>
            const additional_stylers=true;
        
            // pseudo random number generator
            const mt_rand=function(a,b){
                return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( b - a + 1 ) + a );
            };
            
            /*
                These correspond to the colours of the icons available within
                the default icons found number 1-5:
                https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m[N].png
                
                There is no Green...
            */
            const colours={
                'Blue':{
                    color:'#0000ff',
                    compliment:'#ff8000'
                },
                'Yellow':{
                    color:'#fbf6d1',
                    compliment:'#f1d1fb'
                },
                'Red':{
                    color:'#f1d7d7',
                    compliment:'#d89595'
                },
                'Pink':{
                    color:'#f08194',
                    compliment:'#f09381'
                },
                'Purple':{
                    color:'#9365f7',
                    compliment:'#a387de'
                }
            };
            
            function initMap(){
                /*
                    set the map with basic options
                    - append the new MapTypeIds
                */
                let latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( 51, 4 );
                let options = {
                    zoom:8,
                    center:latlng,
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControlOptions:{
                        mapTypeIds:[ 'roadmap' ].concat( Object.keys( colours ) ),
                    }
                };
                const map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
                

                
                // set up the colours for themes and icons/markers
                let rgb={};
                
                
                /*
                    for each colour, add a new map styler and 
                    create some markers - these are not yet 
                    added to the map.
                */
                Object.keys(colours).forEach( ( colour,index ) => {
                    /* set the custom style rules */
                    let rules=[
                        { featureType:'administrative', elementType:'all',stylers:[ { visibility:'on' } ] }
                    ];
                    
                    if( additional_stylers ){
                        rules.push({ featureType:'road', elementType:'geometry', stylers:[ { color:colours[colour].compliment } ] });
                        rules.push({ featureType:'water', elementType:'geometry.fill', stylers:[ { color:colours[colour].color } ] });
                        /* other rules... */
                    };
                    
                    rgb[colour]={
                        'markers':[],
                        'style':new google.maps.StyledMapType( rules, { name:colour } )
                    };
                    
                    map.mapTypes.set( colour, rgb[colour].style );
                    
                    
                    /*
                        generate a varying number of markers for each 
                        cluster colour || or just 20 as per original...
                    */
                    for( let i=0; i < ( 20 * ( index + 1 + mt_rand(1,10) ) ); i++ ){
                        let mkr=new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng( 51.11 - Math.random(), 4.11 - Math.random() ),
                            colour:colour,
                            title:i.toString(),
                            icon:{
                                url:'//maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/'+colour.toLowerCase()+'.png',
                                labelOrigin:new google.maps.Point(16,-15)
                            },
                            label:{
                                text:i.toString(),
                                fontFamily:'monospace',
                                fontSize:'1rem',
                                fontWeight:'bold',
                                color:colour,
                                className:[ 'label', colour.toLowerCase() ].join(' ')
                            }
                        });
                        // store the new marker
                        rgb[colour].markers.push( mkr );
                    }
                });
                
                
                
                const calculator=function( markers, numStyles ) {
                    return { 
                        text:[ markers[0].colour, markers.length ].join( String.fromCharCode(32) ),
                        index:Object.keys(colours).indexOf( markers[0].colour ) + 1
                    }
                };
                
                


                /*
                    Create the clusterer with NO markers
                    and assign the (undocumented) calculator.
                    
                    The calculator function has been simplified
                    using the array of colours defined earlier.
                */
                let oCluster=new MarkerClusterer( map, [], {
                    imagePath:'//developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
                }); 
                oCluster.setCalculator( calculator );
                
                
                /*
                    Listen for maptype change events
                    and initialise the clusterer with
                    the respective set of markers if,
                    and only if, the selected maptype
                    is a named colour.
                */
                map.addListener('maptypeid_changed',()=>{
                    let colour=map.getMapTypeId();
                    oCluster.clearMarkers();
                    
                    if( Object.keys(colours).includes( colour ) ){
                        oCluster.addMarkers( rgb[colour].markers, false );
                        oCluster.fitMapToMarkers();
                    }
                }); 
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Proof of concept jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/m1gvhecy/9/)

[image: Example output]

Comment: @MrUpsidown to be fair I was having fun writing it - but I do, at times, perhaps go a little far